# How to change Vuetify v-text-input component's time format from am/pm to 24 hours

Tags: vuetify.js

According to my client's requirement I'm using Vuetify's v-text-field to show time field instead of timepicker and I want to show it by 24 hours format and to remove clock icon from the field. My code is like below,

```
<v-text-field
  value="12:30:00"
  type="time"
></v-text-field>
```

I tried passing `format="24hr"` props like in time picker component but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the `format` property of the `v-time-picker` and not the `v-text-field` and to remove the clock from the `v-text-field` you will just have to remove the `prepend-icon` property from it.

Here's a modified CodePen from the official docs, showing the changes: https://codepen.io/pmtarkan/pen/JjJjQXr

Answer (score 0):

in case it is still useful to you, I have created a **DigitalTimePicker** that, unlike the TimePicker, is a simpler and more minimalist version.

If you want to take a look
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-more-component